# Failing to write a complex condition

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the **comments** of the **post** that has a **commnet** from the logged in user.

Suppose I commented on a facebook post and with my **if condition** I want to display later comments of the same post.

The logged in user id = **$id**

I tried this condition:
if($comment_uid== $id || $row['p_post_id'] = $row['c_post_id'])

Currently its displaying all the rows

```php
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.post_id AS c_post_id,
       c.comment_id,
       c.comment,
       c.user_id AS c_uid,
       u.username,
       u.dp,
       c.is_marked,
       p.user_id AS p_uid,
       p.post_id AS p_post_id
FROM comment c
INNER JOIN user u ON c.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN post p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
ORDER BY c.comment_id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($result) {
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($noti_result)) {
$post = $row['c_post_id'];
$comment = $row['comment'];
$username = $row['username'];
$comment_uid = $row['c_uid'];
$post_uid= $row['p_uid'];

if($comment_uid== $id || $row['p_post_id'] = $row['c_post_id'])
{
echo  $username also said $comment</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: What is the failure?

Comment: its showing all the rows

Comment: Ah, I see. So you need to restrict the query to a single `user_id`.

Comment: Why is there a join between post and comments table on ```user_id``` if the ```$id``` is to deal only with ```comments.user_id```?

Comment: restricting a single user_id will show the comments of the logged in user. I mean the own comments

Comment: i have more function of it later @KalpashreeV.Bal

Comment: I would suggest adding one more condition ```c.post_id = p.id``` (and/or depends upon your choice). What is the difference between the "comments of the logged in user" and "the own comments"?

Comment: also, you probably want to use ```==``` in ```$row['p_post_id'] = $row['c_post_id']```